# How can check the email address exist or not before send the reset link while forgot password in magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2.3.4

*Please help me to check is email exists or not in while password reset. Magento 2.3.4*

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email'); 
    if ($email) {
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($email, \Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress::class)) {
            $this->session->setForgottenEmail($email);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('The email address is incorrect. Verify the email address and try again.')
            );
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotpassword');
        }

        try {
            $this->customerAccountManagement->initiatePasswordReset(
                $email,
                AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET
            );
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
            // Do nothing, we don't want anyone to use this action to determine which email accounts are registered.
        } catch (SecurityViolationException $exception) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($exception->getMessage());
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotpassword');
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                $exception,
                __('We\'re unable to send the password reset email.')
            );
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotpassword');
        }
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($this->getSuccessMessage($email));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please enter your email.'));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotpassword');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be security risk as any one can check if some user have account on the website or not. Then he just have to guess a password. So, message should be always success.

If you want to change it, you can modify the logic in magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.phpin initiatePasswordReset method where customer is loaded. You can check if customer exists and throw error like,

```
$this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('The email address is does not exist. Verify the email address and try again.')
```

But **I would strongly suggest not to change this logic as that would be security flaw.**